# Create a function that will format the number provided as an argument with a dollar sign, commas and two decimal places

Tags: mysql

I am new to MYSQL and I need to write a function to format a number in such a way that provide as an argument with a dollar sign, commas and two decimal places such as:
for example: $99,999.99

I have a column of salary that need to be formatted

SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME, DOLLAR_FMT(SALARY) AS SALARY
FROM EMPLOYEES;

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...,
  CONCAT('$', FORMAT(SALARY, 2)) AS SALARY
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

Read about the FORMAT() function here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format